# Chrome beta and canary builds not displaying Arial Black fonts

Tags: css, google-chrome

I have noticed in the beta and canary builds of Google Chrome that my webpage no longer displays any text with the font-family "Arial Black" (its like the font does not exist and is using the default browser font). My webpage displays properly with version 36.

Is there anything that has changed from 36 to the beta and canary builds that I am not aware of? Can anyone else seem to replicate this problem?

Comment: Maybe report it as a bug (with example code) to the developers?!?

Comment: Using Google Canary v39.0.2146.0, I can confirm problem in font rendering too.